# Prefered Apache Tomcat version on production servers for Grails app

Tags: tomcat, grails

We are using Grails 2.5.0. Every Grails release recommends some plugin version for tomcat plugin (and some others), so Grails 2.5.0 recommends Tomcat plugin 7.0.55.2.

When we go to production servers, is it necessary to use actually the same version of Tomcat on the production server for deployment or we can use other upgraded version on same release like 1.7.xx?

Well, we have not faced any issues related to this yet in last 2-3 years but I want a more clarification on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been staying with the latest 7.x version of Tomcat for the various Tomcat plugin releases and using the latest plugin version when releasing a new version of Grails. In parallel we've also been releasing new versions of the plugin using Tomcat 8, and that's currently at version 8.0.21.

Tomcat 8 is quite stable at this point and supports the Servlet 3.1 spec, whereas Tomcat 7 only supports 3.0, so Tomcat 8 should be a drop-in replacement for Tomcat 7 and you'd be able to use newer features if you want. Additionally it should be faster and use less memory, but I haven't seen any formal benchmarks.

Having said that, the tomcat plugin used for `run-app` has next to nothing to do with what you use in production. In general any recent servlet container (i.e. one that supports Servlet API 2.5+) should work fine since Grails wars are self-contained standard war files. You can use Jetty, WebLogic, JBoss, etc.

In general you should use libraries and servers in development that are fairly close to what will be used in production, but it's not a requirement, just a good idea since you're more likely to catch inconsistencies earlier. The same goes for the database - use the default in-memory H2 database to get started, and continue using it if you use H2 in production, but use a local MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle/etc. server that's similar in version and configuration to your test and production servers.

Comment: Thank you, Burt for clarification on this. Although Tomcat 8 have some new features and improvements we can stick with the latest 7.x version of Tomcat for now since Grails has been heavily used & tested with Tomcat 7.

Comment: Makes sense - if it's not broken, don't fix it :)